# lxc launch hangs for lxd

Tags: 15.04, lxc, container, lxd

New to lxd, and follow the article https://insights.ubuntu.com/2015/04/28/getting-started-with-lxd-the-container-lightervisor/ , also refer the https://github.com/lxc/lxd for upgrading to latest lxd

I can get the result from `lxc image list images:` command

```
root@lxd:~# lxc image list images:
+--------------------------------+--------------+--------+-------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+
|             ALIAS              | FINGERPRINT  | PUBLIC |       DESCRIPTION       |  ARCH   |          UPLOAD DATE          |
+--------------------------------+--------------+--------+-------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+
|                                | 8d552ca0de3c | yes    | Centos 6 (amd64)        | x86_64  | Jun 17, 2015 at 11:17am (CST) |
|                                | f7d9e7940fbb | yes    | Centos 6 (amd64)        | x86_64  | Jun 18, 2015 at 11:17am (CST) |
....
```

While I try to launch the container by

```
root@lxd:~# lxc launch images:ubuntu/trusty/i386 ubuntu-32
Creating container...
```

It just hangs there, any suggestion for the problem or where is the log message for debug ?

below is the env.

```
root@lxd:~# lxc --version
0.7
root@lxd:~# lxd --version
0.13
root@lxd:~# uname -a
Linux lxd 3.19.0-15-generic #15-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 16 23:32:37 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@lxd:~# cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=15.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=vivid
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 15.04"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just slow for network with less progress information in console. see reported [issue #833:add status of downloading in lxd-images import](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/833)